# Implementing HeartBeat in Atmosphere Framework (Android)

Tags: java, android, atmosphere

1)How can we Implement Heart Beat in Android. 
      I already Implemented Atmosphere framework.

Currently what happening is webscoket connection got dismissed which we are not able to Identify

Comment: why this question is closed?